# Sending Multiple AJAX request to Add Product To Cart Failing

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add a few **different** products to the woocommerce "cart" via AJAX. It is super simple but, it fails. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({url: "/wordpress/?post_type=product&add-to-cart=" + p_id,
      statusCode: {
        200: function() {
          console.log('/wordpress/?post_type=product&add-to-cart=' + p_id);
          console.log('It Worked');
        }
      }
    }
);
```

I have also done:

```
$.get('/wordpress/?post_type=product&add-to-cart=' + p_id, function() {
         console.log('/wordpress/?post_type=product&add-to-cart=' + p_id);
});
```

I am calling this in a function multiple times for each product. The first product that I get the console.log from is the only one that was added. How do I fix this? Again to re-cap, 
**GOAL**: Add multiple different products to the cart all at once with AJAX. Maybe do I need to create a custom php script that I call from AJAX?

Thanks ~

Comment: You need a loop to iterate through each item in the cart

Comment: Yes, I have a loop that calls this function for each item and adds it to the cart. But only one gets added. Maybe is there a certain time you need to wait between each call to add?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is competing ajax requests. So within every loop you start a new request but the add-to-cart action only accepts one at a time and is blocking the other ones.

**Solution:** Wait for the success trigger of your ajax call before setting up the next request.

e.g. like so:

```
var i = 0;
var arrayProductIds = [1,2,3];

(function makeAjaxRequest() {
  $.post('?add-to-cart=' + arrayProductIds[i], function() {

    // success, so start next request
    i++;
    if (i === arrayProductIds.length){
      // all products have been added
    }else{
      makeAjaxRequest();
    }
  });
})();
```